# Angular js ng-click object with logical not ( ! ) by default true or false

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

```
<p ng-click = "editing = !editing"> edit </p>
{{!editing}}
```

By default `{{!editing}}` print true, and when I click on edit it also show true.
My question is why logical not ( `!` ) showing true.

Comment: working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/17h317km/

Comment: you should use Logic like following  "editing == !editing " that is the Syntax

Comment: my question is why "    {{!editing}}  " is by default showinh true cause there I am using logical not (!).  @N.V.Prasad

Comment: If you want Why  is that Happening You need to Update a Fiddle with Related code Can you  ? that helps to find What's happening

Comment: please go through https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/17h317km/ this link @N.V.Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize editing variable with ng-init to the desired value. By default value should be false (as it's value is undefined).

```
<p ng-init="editing==true" ng-click = "editing = !editing"> edit </p>
{{!editing}}
```